# tc-qfq is classless error

Tags: linux, networking, traffic-shaping, tc

I'm using Linux 3.0.101 with iproute2-3.4.0 on a router and I'm getting this error:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth2.2 root handle 1: qfq
--> OK

tc class add dev eth2.2 parent 1: classid 1:10 qfq weight 1
--> Error: Qdisc "qfq" is classless.
```

`sch_qfq.ko` was loaded with insmod before and is in use according to lsmod after the qdisc is added.

Comment: qfq is classful.
http://wiki.linuxwall.info/doku.php/en:ressources:dossiers:networking:traffic_control#qfq_-_quick_fair_queueing
Example: https://github.com/sivasankariit/qfq-rl/blob/master/qfq.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the Makefile of iproute2/tc had this line:

```
#TCMODULES += q_qfq.o
```

Obviously, if this is commented out then tc cannot build and later cannot load the `q_qfq.so` and therefore assumes qfq is classless.